# I'm having trouble with my Accordion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with my Accordion.

**The issue:** Everything is working as it should but I have one problem.

I'm using click eventListener to clean all Accordions triggers * (buttons)* when I find more then *1 closeIt* class.

The issue is, if I don't close an active Accordion it won't add the active class because it cleans everything.

```js
function showAcord(n) {
  var $bro = "magic-" + n,
    $par = document.getElementById($bro);

  var $j = document.getElementsByClassName('acord-active'),
    i = $j.length;

  while (i--) {
    $j[i].classList.remove("acord-active");
  }

  $par.classList.toggle("acord-active");

  // Close It Condição
  var $myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('closeIt');

  var $selector = "btn-" + n,
    $btn = document.getElementById($selector);

  if ($btn.classList.contains("closeIt")) {
    var $j = document.getElementsByClassName('acord-active'),
      i = $j.length;

    while (i--) {
      $j[i].classList.remove("acord-active");
    }

    var $checkIcons = document.getElementsByClassName('closeIt'),
      y = $checkIcons.length;

    while (y--) {
      $checkIcons[y].classList.remove("closeIt");
    }

  } else {
    $btn.classList.toggle("closeIt");
  }
}

// EventListener
(function() {
  window.addEventListener('click', clean);

  function clean() {
    var $cleaner = document.getElementsByClassName('closeIt');
    var $loop = $cleaner.length;

    if ($loop > 1) {
      while ($loop--) {
        $cleaner[$loop].classList.remove("closeIt");
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

```css
.openIt:before {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.closeIt:before {
  content: "\f077";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f6a61d;
}

.acord-off {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  position: absolute !important;
}

.acord-active {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  position: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <div class="col-sm-12 pt-3 mb-5 aligncenter">
      <h2>Ibbca Accordeon</h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn btn-info openIt" name="button" onclick="showAcord(1)" id="btn-1">Mostrar acord 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn btn-info openIt" name="button" onclick="showAcord(2)" id="btn-2">Mostrar acord 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="magic-1" class="acord-1 acord-off">
        <p>Texto II</p>
      </div>
      <div id="magic-2" class="acord-2 acord-off">
        <p>Texto III</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: What is an *acordeon*? You mean *Accordion*?

Comment: Yes!! I'll change that

Comment: When do you want to close the Accordion? on window click?

Comment: The accordion is working fine, the issue is the button. It changes to active class when the accordion is open, but i doesn't work if i try to open another acordion using another button. It wont change to active.

Comment: So you want to open both accordion when you click both button? Or you want to open one at a time?

Comment: In this case i have 2 buttons and 2 hidden text. The hidden text is working perfectly however the button isn't. I want to add active class to the button, changing the color and icon, but this isn't working because it keeps cleaning the active class with eventListener whenever i try to open the second text (the text opens but the active class from the button is cleaned up). Its only working atm when i close the text (cleaning the active class from the button) and open the second text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the snippet. 
Remove the below code from the javascript function if you want to keep the accordion open on same button's second click.

```
if($par.classList.contains("acord-active")){
    $par.classList.remove("acord-active");
    $btn.classList.remove("closeIt");

    return;
}
```

```js
function showAcord(n) {
  var $par = document.getElementById("magic-" + n);

  var $btn = document.getElementById("btn-" + n);

//REMOVE BELOW CONDITION IF YOU WANT TO KEEP THE ACCORDION OPEN ON SAME BUTTON'S SECOND CLICK.
    if($par.classList.contains("acord-active")){
      $par.classList.remove("acord-active");
      $btn.classList.remove("closeIt");
      
      return;
    }


  var $j = document.getElementsByClassName('acord-active'),
    i = $j.length;

  while (i--) {
    $j[i].classList.remove("acord-active");
  }

  $par.classList.toggle("acord-active");

  // Close It Condição
  var $myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('closeIt');
   var $myClassi = $myClass.length;

  while ($myClassi--) {
    $myClass[$myClassi].classList.remove("closeIt");
  }

  if ($btn.classList.contains("closeIt")) {     
    $btn.classList.remove("closeIt");
  } else {
    $btn.classList.add("closeIt");
  }
}
```

```css
.openIt:before {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.closeIt:before {
  content: "\f077";
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f6a61d;
}

.acord-off {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  position: absolute !important;
}

.acord-active {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  position: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article>
    <div class="col-sm-12 pt-3 mb-5 aligncenter">
      <h2>Ibbca Accordeon</h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn btn-info openIt" name="button" onclick="showAcord(1)" id="btn-1">Mostrar acord 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn btn-info openIt" name="button" onclick="showAcord(2)" id="btn-2">Mostrar acord 2</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="magic-1" class="acord-1 acord-off">
        <p>Texto II</p>
      </div>
      <div id="magic-2" class="acord-2 acord-off">
        <p>Texto III</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i want only one accodion to open and the active class on the buttons to work properly. The only issue im having is the button active class (closeIt), it's being cleaned if i have more then 1 closeIt class (as it should) but it doesn't work properly if i have an existing closeIt class and try to open another text, in this case i have no closeIt class but even so the text is shown (again, as it should)

Comment: Understood. Now lets say you clicked on Button-1. It will open Accordion-1. Now again you are clicking on Button-1 then what should happen? Should it close the Accordion-1 or keep it open?

Comment: I have updated the above answer as per your need.. Let me know if still not as per your need!

Comment: going to test it!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey take care of the event propagation, you attached to the window the function `clean` everytime is clicked. If you click a btn this event is bubbling to the window and it runs `clean`. You can avoid this like this:

if you add `onclick="showAcord(event, 1)`

and then

`function showAcord(event, n) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      ...`

this way you avoid cleaning when a `btn` is clicked